# Can a ungrounded electrical system damage computer parts, such as a Wi-Fi card?

Tags: desktop-computer, pci-express, ground

I bought an assembled PC, with components chosen by me, at a specialized store. The PC was new and was tested after assembly by the store technician.

I used the PC for a couple of hours, with no problems at all. The OS was Windows 10, free version.

The Wi-Fi card model is: TP-Link 300 Mbps Wireless N PCI Express Adapter, TL-WN881ND.

I disconnected the PCIe card and installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS without problems.

When reinserting the PCIe card with my right hand and touching a metal pipe with my left hand I got a intense electrical discharge, I felt it in both hands.

I also found more than 120 GB of log files, kern.log and syslog each 60 GB in size. They were lines of the same error repeated countless times.

The error is the following (I don't know exactly, but I will update this question later):
`PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer`

**Update**: The full error is:

```
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, 
type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:06ba] error   
status/mask=00000001/00002000
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
```

It is a bug caused by ASPM. You have to modify the grub2 file in `/etc/default/grub` in this way: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"`
See https://askubuntu.com/questions/863150/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-physical-layer-id-00e5receiver-id#

Comment: If you left the computer plugged into ungrounded AC or did not observe proper static electricity precautions, yes, you can damage parts.  You should get an electrician to provide you with a safe, preferably grounded, AC outlet for your computer.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, return the PC! This is obviously unsafe, if you got a severe shock (not just a mild "tingle" from leakage). Attempting to ground a chassis that is so far above ground potential is a fire hazard.

Certainly, there is *some* leakage expected across a power supply due to capacitive coupling, but that should allow no more than a few mA AC to flow, which could cause a barely-detectable "tingling" sensation, most noticeable if you pass a hand gently over the surface. If the PC is grounded, then the power supply could have points a 5 to 12 VDC off ground, which would not create an electric shock unless your hands were soaked in salt water and touching both ground and "live" wire.

A shock that is felt as *severe* indicates that substantial AC current is flowing from the mains to the components. Grounding that, if you're lucky, will create a *big* spark, melt some parts, and blow the mains circuit breaker. If you're *not* lucky, it could also start a fire.

**The only part of the PC that should have mains (120 VAC or 240 VAC) current is in the *power supply***; any wire coming *out* of the power supply should be floating, or a few volts from ground, at  most.